Key combinations in VSC for C++
I am trying to find a fast way to compile and run my programs without having to move my hand from the keyboard to the mouse. I know this may seem lazy but some of you will see that streamlining a process is fully understandable. Anyway, I know the combination to compile is (Ctrl + B) but I cannot for the life of me find the combination to run the program.
I tried the combination (Ctrl + R) which I thought would make sense to be the run command but it didn't work.

Please note, there is MS Visual Studio vs. MS Visual Studio Code. These are two distinct IDEs. From your question and tags, I'm not sure which one you address...

If you actually mean VS Code, the answer depends on the extension and build system. A fresh VS Code installation doesn't have any C++ support. The extension details in VS Code should describe it. E.g. the CMake Tools have `cmake.launchTarget
Run Without Debugging
Ctrl
+
F5
commandPalette touchBar`

If you are working with the IDE "Microsoft Visual Studio", try "Ctrl + F5" for running the code without debugging. If you want to run the code with debugging, the shortcut would be just "F5".

This is rather a comment than an answer. You cannot comment unless you have 50 points of reputation.
